# Can nvlink inline device functions from separate compilation units?

Tags: cuda, inline, link-time-optimization, nvlink

If the separate compilation units that are fed as input to `nvlink` contain cuda kernels and device functions that invoke device functions marked as `__forceinline__`, will these functions be inlined?  Assume they would be inlined if one put all the source code into a single file.

Answer (score 1):

> If the separate compilation units that are fed as input to nvlink contain cuda kernels and device functions that invoke device functions marked as `__forceinline__`, will these functions be inlined?

To the best of my knowledge, the CUDA device code linker can't do this. The `__forceinline__` directive is a compiler level operation, and after compilation there is no way of marking code as inlineable in either PTX or SASS. The CUDA device code compiler should emit a warning that an external inline function was used but not defined if you try this.

If you want functions to be compiled inline, you have to (unsurprisingly) use a compiler, not a linker.